# Using awk command for fetching data

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a log file, which is updating every second. I want to fetch the last 10 minutes of data. I tried awk like this:

```
awk \ -v time1="$(date +"%F %R" --date=@$(expr `date +%s` - 600))" \
-v time2="$(date "+%F %R")" \
'$0 ~ time1, $0 ~ time2' \ filename
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Give sample data for the file, clearly mentioning the column(s) where time is getting stored and your expected output.

Comment: Whats with all the backslashes before spaces?

Comment: 170605 01405005      xxxxx  DS1O     XXXXXXXXX  From (,,XXXX,XXXXX) XXXX01: WEB WRITE RESPONSE  00000000  00000000    
170605 01410524      xxxx DS1O     XXXXXXXXX  From (,,XXXX,XXXXX) XXXX01: WEB WRITE RESPONSE  00000000  00000000    
170605 01415207      xxxxx DS1O     XXXXXXXXX  From (,,XXXX,XXXXX) XXXX01: WEB WRITE RESPONSE  00000000  00000000    01:41:52
error code: 203, pc=354, call=1, seg=0^@
170605 01595005      xxxx DS1O     XXXX01  From (,,XXXX) FINAL 
170605 01595012      xxxx  DS1O     XXXX01  From (,,XXXX,XXXXX) XXXX01: WEB WRITE RESPONSE  00000000  00000000

Comment: My requirement is to fetch lines with error code from a log file for every 10 minutes where the lines with error are not having timestamp. So i cant use grep or sed. I can use awk. How to write this in shell script?

Comment: Tried another awk. But its grepping all errors: time1=$(date +%y:%m:%d:" "%I:%M:%S) time2=$(date +%y:%m:%d" "%I:%M:%S -d '600 seconds ago')                                                      (awk -v d1=time1 -v d2=time2 '$1$2 -ge d1 && $1$2 -le d2 || $0 ~ d2' /var/..../outfile.txt | grep -i "Error").

Comment: You have to [edit] the question, not add comments to it. It's impossible to understand the formatting of your input as all the whitespace disappears.